# Why JavaScript "length in array" gives different result for arrays having one element or more elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In chrome 87, the `length in array` gives following output:

```
length in ['test']
false
```

but if we try with more elements, it outputs following:

```
length in ['test', 'test2']
true
```

Can somebody explain these different outputs?

Comment: What is the value of `length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `length` you're using refers not to the `'length'` property, but the value contained in the global identifier `length`, which exists on `window`. `window.length` is, [per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length):

> Returns the number of frames (either `<frame>` or `<iframe>` elements) in the window.

So, your code will produce that result if you have exactly 1 frame or iframe in the window - since the second array has a `[1]` property, but the first array does not have a `[1]` property.

Live snippet illustrating this:

```js
// NOTE THE EXISTENCE OF ONE IFRAME in the HTML

console.log(length in ['test']);
console.log(length in ['test', 'test2']);
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

Similarly:

```js
const length = 3;
console.log(
  length in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // true; more than 3 items
);
console.log(
  length in [0, 1] // false; less than 3 items
);
```

Answer (score 2):

`length` in your snippets is a variable, which I assume is defined somewhere else and has some value. Depending on its value `length in [0, 1]` can return `true` or `false`.
Since you mentioned Chrome, I assume you're running this snippet in chrome dev tools. In this case `length` is a global variable (actually, it's a property of window: [`window.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length)). Check its value - it's probably `1`. This explains why `1 in ['test']` is false (there is no element with index `1` here), but `1 in ['test1', 'test2']` is `true.

If you want to check a presence of a property "length", you need to have it as a string:

```
'length' in []
```

In this case it will return `true` for any array - because all arrays have the "length" property